# How to write relative path for subdirectory domain

Tags: php, wordpress, relative-path

I am creating a new Wordpress site using some temporary IP address with sub directory, this is the [site](http://192.250.225.237/~churchinatlanta)

All the files stored under this sub directory , now I wants to give relative paths for the images in the pages and post .

[image]

I want to give relative url for the above image ..

help me guys I am newbie here how to give all the
/../ methods are failed help me

Comment: Please share your code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you have to use the `get_template_directory_uri()` function to get path to the template directory and then you can use the path to the folder you wish.

Suppose your folder structure is tamil>images>new.jpg where `tamil` is your theme folder name and then images folder which has the image.

The code should be

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/new.jpg">
```